# Display popover with bootstrap validator correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, popover

I'm trying to use popover to display error messages using the [bootstrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) plugin.

The problem is when I click the tab key over all required fields, the popover will be shown for all fields. I need it to be shown only on the focused field which has error.

I have implemented an example to add issue here on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16417/), and it worked ! But when I applied it on my page it didn't work right.

I've tried to remove all jQuery libraries and css and the problem is still there. Here is [my actual code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16580/).

```
$('#validform').on('invalid.bs.validator valid.bs.validator', function (e) {

               var message = e.detail;
               var target = e.relatedTarget;

                $(target).popover('destroy');
                $(target).popover({
                    trigger: 'focus',
                    placement: 'top',
                    container: 'body',
                    content: message
                });
                $(target).popover('show');

                if(e.type === 'valid'){
                    $(target).popover('destroy');
               }
});
```

Comment: you can show form code?

Comment: I added my html on jsfiddle and didn't work !! https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16580/ @DanielArenas

Comment: You've just forgotten change the id of form  `$('#theform').on('invalid.bs.validator valid.bs.validator', function (e) {`

Comment: ok that was mistake by me, but it works on jsfiddle only ! but locally not :( @DanielArenas

Comment: you can try add `return;` in the end code, but this is not best practice, this must work without return, you should have some class strange